# Convertir hora a otra zona horaria

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Trabajo en C#
Tengo una hora 02:40:27 que viene de España lo que intento es cambiar a la hora de Chile 14:40:27

He intentado lo siguiente

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime fecha;
        string hora = string.Empty;

        fecha = Convert.ToDateTime("2022-08-24T00:00:00");
        hora = "02:40:27";// hora de España

        var year = fecha.Year;
        var mes = Convert.ToInt32(fecha.ToString("MM"));
        var dia = fecha.Day;

        string[] subs = hora.Split(':');

        var hours = Convert.ToInt32(subs[0]);
        var minuto = Convert.ToInt32(subs[1]);
        var segundo = Convert.ToInt32(subs[2]);

        CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTime newDT = new DateTime(year, mes, dia, hours, minuto, segundo);

        Console.WriteLine(newDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", ci));
        
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Pero como resultado me sale lo siguiente: `2022-08-24 02:40:27 AM`
Lo que espero es lo siguiente: `2022-08-24 14:40:27 PM`

Comment: ¿Por qué esperas  una hora en el futuro? No tiene sentido. De españa a chile son 6 horas de diferencia. Yo esperaría `2022-08-23 8:40:27 PM`. Revisa este [pequeño ejemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OcE5Am).

Comment: Puedes usar [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=net-6.0). [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones) tienes varios ejemplos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas, en tu código veo que el CultureInfo lo has puesto InvariantCulture, prueba a sustituir la línea por:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-CL");
```